# PQYT Make QGridLayout scrollable

Tags: python, image, pyqt5

I was wondering if it is possible to add a QScrollArea to a QGridLayout? Below is my attempt however, it always fails with the error.

```
TypeError: setWidget(self, QWidget): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QGridLayout'
```

Is this method only possible for combo and list boxes? I am basically passing QPixmap images into a QGridLayout which needs to be scrolled. Any help much appreciated thank you.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class PicClip(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Load image
        self.im = QPixmap("1.jpg")
        self.im1 = QPixmap("1.jpg")
        # Label 1
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setPixmap(self.im)
        # Label 2
        self.label1 = QLabel()
        self.label1.setPixmap(self.im1)
        # Make Grid
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        # Create widgets to grid
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label1, 1, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        # Set layout of Grid
        self.setLayout(self.grid)
        # Scroll 
        scroll = QScrollArea()
        scroll.setWidget(self.grid)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        # Show 
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = PicClip()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.grid` is layout and you are trying to add layout using `setWidget` function. `setWidget` function only gets `QWidget`

simple trick is to add wrapper `QWidget` and set `self.grid` as its layout

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class PicClip(QMainWindow): # I modified this line to show window properly

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Load image
        self.im = QPixmap("1.jpg")
        self.im1 = QPixmap("1.jpg")
        # Label 1
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setPixmap(self.im)
        # Label 2
        self.label1 = QLabel()
        self.label1.setPixmap(self.im1)
        # Make Grid
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        # Create widgets to grid
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label1, 1, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        # Set layout of Grid
        self.setLayout(self.grid)
        # Scroll
        scroll = QScrollArea()
        # add wrapper widget and set its layout
        wrapper_widget = QWidget()
        wrapper_widget.setLayout(self.grid)
        scroll.setWidget(wrapper_widget)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        # Show
        self.setCentralWidget(scroll)  # I modified this line to show window properly
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = PicClip()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thank you so much I did think about adding a wrapper as that's what I would have done in Tkinter i'm new to PYQT. I will study your answer and update my knowledge according. Have a great day !

Comment: @EddieWebb that is not a "wrapper", is an actual widget (which, in this case, is considered as a "container"). In any case, for future reference, always check the documentation for arguments: as you can see in the [`setWidget()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#setWidget) reference (and as *the name also hints*), the argument can only be a *widget*, not a layout. I strongly urge you to carefully read more about [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) so that you better understand the difference between the *basic* Qt class for **all** widgets, [QWidget](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html)

Comment: @musicamante understood thanks! I will make a coffee and have a read of those articles shortly. One side question do I need to set the size of the widget to make the window size correctly. As now it opens smaller than the images I am loading.

Comment: @EddieWebb see the [`sizeAdjustPolicy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#sizeAdjustPolicy-prop) property: `scroll.sizeAdjustPolicy(scroll.AdjustToContents)` *before* showing anything.

Comment: @musicamante fantastic thanks for your time. I have learned a lot today.